# how to add rows to a matrix to achieve a given order

Tags: matrix

I have a large number of matrices having equal numbers of columns but different numbers of rows. Say, their order is n X 4, Where n can be any integer between 1000 to 1050. How to tell Mathematica to add 1050-n dummy rows to a matrix of order n X 4 so that all of them have same order of 1050 X 4. The dummy column could be anything, say {a, a, a, a}.

Comment: Take a look at [``PadRight``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html).

Comment: `n = 8;
PadRight[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 4}], {1050, Automatic}, 
  a] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `t` contains matrices, whose dimensions are:

```
Dimensions /@ t
```

> {{10, 4}, {13, 4}, {11, 4}, {10, 4}}

Here I am assuming that I am going to make every matrix a {15,4} dimension matrix. Create dummy arrays: (replace 15 with 1050 in your case)

```
darrays = ConstantArray[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 15 - Dimensions[#][[1]]] & /@ t

result = MapThread[Join[#1, #2] &, {t, darrays}];

Dimensions /@ result
```

> {{15, 4}, {15, 4}, {15, 4}, {15, 4}}

Answer (score 6):

You may use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html).

For a matrix `m`

```
MatrixForm[m = Partition[Range[16], 4]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then add 2 rows with `SparseArray`

```
MatrixForm@SparseArray[m, {6, 4}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`Band` can be used to place `m` in the new matrix. For example, to start `m` at the second row.

```
MatrixForm@SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> m, {6, 4}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The default value can be changed with the third argument of `SparseArray`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

nbrRows = 10; (* = 1050 in your actual problem *)

Format[a[m_, n_]] := Subscript[a, Row[{m, , n}]]

SeedRandom[123];
```

`matrices` represents your original matrices

```
Row[MatrixForm /@
  (matrices = Table[n = RandomInteger[{3, nbrRows}];
     Array[a, {n, 4}], 3])]
```

[image]

`newMatrices` are the padded matrices with the specified [`Dimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html)

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ (newMatrices = (PadRight[#, nbrRows, pad] & /@ 
  matrices) /. pad -> ConstantArray[a, 4])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
m = Partition[Range[16], 4]

ArrayReshape[m, {4,0}+Dimensions[m],a]//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
             \begin{array}{cccc}
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
              9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
              13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
              a & a & a & a \\
              a & a & a & a \\
              a & a & a & a \\
              a & a & a & a \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

```
m//ArrayReshape[#, {4,0}+Dimensions[m]]&//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
             \begin{array}{cccc}
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
              9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
              13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
              0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

```
filler = Function[{matrices, len, fill},
  With[{
    n = Length[matrices],
    cols = Last@Dimensions@First@matrices
    },
   PadRight[matrices, {n, len, cols}, fill]]]
```

E.g., `filler[matrices,1050,a]`.